# I am trying to build a shiny dashboard and I am facing a problem regarding how to update a plot conditionally

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

In the first stage the user  can select from a dropdown (say, Dropdown - 1) certain items. Based on the user selection a next level of dropdown (say, Dropdown - 2) appears. The code works fine up to this part.
I want to visualize my plot based on the user selection in Dropdown - 2. However, I cannot execute this part of the code as I cannot store the value in any variable. Can some one please help?

```
library(shiny)
thematic::thematic_shiny(font = "auto")
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyUI(
  
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "XYZ Data"),
    dashboardSidebar(collapsed = F,
                     sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                 menuItem("Home", icon = icon("house") ),
                                 menuItem("Compare Models", icon = icon("magnifying-glass"), newtab = F),
                                 menuItem("Data visualization", icon = icon("database"), newtab = F),
                                 menuItem("Predict Position", icon = icon("fa-duotone fa-chart-simple"), newtab = F)
                     )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidPage(
        uiOutput("analysisType"),
        uiOutput("nextLayer"),
        verbatimTextOutput("nextLayerInput")
      ),
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                                /*Page background*/
                                .content-wrapper {
                                background-color: #ffff00;
                                }
                                /* logo */
                                .main-header .logo {
                                background-color: #ff456a;
                                }
                                '
        
      )))
    )
  )  
)
```

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$analysisType = renderUI({
    selectInput("analysisType", "Type of Analysis", 
                c("Select", "Simple Analysis", "Complex Analysis", "Deep Analysis"))
  })
    
    x <- reactive({input$analysisType})
    
    output$nextLayer <- renderUI({
      if(x()=='Deep Analysis'){
        selectInput("positionDeep", "Player Position", 
                             c("Select", "CB", "CM", "FW", "GK", "LB", "LWM", "RB", "RWM"),
                             selected = "Select")
      }
      else if (x()=='Complex Analysis'){
        selectInput("positionComplex", "Player Position", 
                    c("Select", "DEF", "MID", "FWD", "GK"),
                    selected = "Select")
      } else {return()}
      })
    
    # I cannot output this part which should change based on the user input in Dropdown - 2
    output$nextLayerInput <- renderText(reactive({output$nextLayer}))
})
```

Can someone help me doing this? Also, someone might help to simplify parts of the code as I am really new to Shiny.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use `conditionalPanel()` as shown below and define a new variable.

```
library(shiny)
thematic::thematic_shiny(font = "auto")
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- shinyUI(
  
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "XYZ Data"),
    dashboardSidebar(collapsed = F,
                     sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                 menuItem("Home", icon = icon("home") ),
                                 menuItem("Compare Models", icon = icon("magnifying-glass", verify_fa = FALSE), newtab = F),
                                 menuItem("Data visualization", icon = icon("database"), newtab = F),
                                 menuItem("Predict Position", icon = icon("fa-duotone fa-chart-simple", verify_fa = FALSE), newtab = F)
                     )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      #fluidPage(
        uiOutput("analysisType"),
        #uiOutput("nextLayer"),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.analysisType == 'Deep Analysis'  ",
          uiOutput("deep")
        ),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.analysisType == 'Complex Analysis'  ",
          uiOutput("complex")
        ),
        verbatimTextOutput("nextLayerInput"),
      #),
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                                /*Page background*/
                                .content-wrapper {
                                background-color: #ffff00;
                                }
                                /* logo */
                                .main-header .logo {
                                background-color: #ff456a;
                                }
                                '
                                
      )))
    )
  )  
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  output$analysisType = renderUI({
    selectInput("analysisType", "Type of Analysis", 
                c("Select", "Simple Analysis", "Complex Analysis", "Deep Analysis"))
  })
  
  #x <- reactive({input$analysisType})
  
  output$deep <- renderUI({
    selectInput("positionDeep", "Player Position", 
                c("Select", "CB", "CM", "FW", "GK", "LB", "LWM", "RB", "RWM"),
                selected = "Select")
  })
  
  output$complex <- renderUI({
    selectInput("positionComplex", "Player Position", 
                c("Select", "DEF", "MID", "FWD", "GK"),
                selected = "Select")
  })
  
  myVar <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$analysisType)) {
      var <- NULL
    }else if(input$analysisType=='Deep Analysis'){
      var <- input$positionDeep
    }else if (input$analysisType=='Complex Analysis'){
      var <- input$positionComplex
    } else {var <- NULL}
    var
  })
  
  # I cannot output this part which should change based on the user input in Dropdown - 2
  output$nextLayerInput <- renderText({req(myVar())})
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```